# ASP.NET 5 vs Node.js as interface to C++ math library

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, node.js, interface

I have a closed source C++ math library for solid modeling and I want to write SPA to display and edit objects in WebGL. Math library and WebGL SPA will have a huge traffic between them using WebSockets

Which server technology is easier to develop, debug and support in this scenario? Does anyone has the performance impact passing data between SPA and C++ through web sockets?

PS: As I can understand there is no way to use existing C++ libraries from C#. So I need to convert them to plain C API. And writing Node.js extensions seems to be much easier. On the other hand debugging Node.js extensions looks harder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to make a bridge library with C++ for CLR (managed C++). It is kind of a hybrid that can call to native C++ code and .NET. Then you can reference this bridge library in C# project.

This is complex thing on its own, so do some research to see if it will work for you. For example, [see this](http://xmight.blogspot.com/2013/04/cli-bridge-to-connect-c-project-to-csharp.html).

Also, take a look at [this](http://www.xinterop.com/).